# Can I pass the result of a Publisher down to a Reactor Context?

Tags: java, grpc, project-reactor

I have a `io.grpc.Context` that comes from a Publisher. Can I pass write that into the Reactor Context?

```
Mono.just(io.grpc.Context.current())
  .contextWrite(grpcContext -> 
    reactor.util.context.Context.of(MY_KEY, grpcContext))
```

Is something like that possible?
The reason is because I have a OnNextOperator hook that I want to listen for this change in grpc.Context

Answer (score 2):

> Is something like that possible?

Not if you want to access the context downstream - context injection is part of the *subscription* signal, which flows upstream from bottom to top. This is in contrast to the other reactive signals (`next`, `error`) which flow downstream from top to bottom.

Your only sensible option if you want to read a value like this downstream is to include it as part of the element itself - usually by using `zip()`, `zipWith()` or similar.